# Meaning of protocol and contract in the context of inheritance and interfaces

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I am reading head first Java by Bert Bates, Kathy Sierra.
I am having a problem understanding the word protocol and contract in the context of inheritance and interfaces.

for example the following paragraph :

> Inheritance lets you guarantee that all classes grouped under a
>   certain supertype have all the methods that the supertype has. In
>   other words, you define a **common protocol** for a set of classes
>   related through inheritance.

and this:

> When you define methods in a superclass, that can be inherited by
>   subclasses, you’re announcing a kind of **protocol** to other code that
>   says, “All my subtypes (i.e. subclasses) can do these things, with
>   these methods that look like this...”
>   In other words, you establish a
>   **contract**.

What does protocol and contract mean and how useful is that in java?

Comment: In the case of OOP it just means method signature, or collection of method signatures.

Comment: Inheriting from @EJP 's comment, They both nearly mean the same things, notice the *in other words*. They simply mean that you force the subtype to provide the basic behaviour specified in the super type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is does protocol and contract mean and how useful is that in
>   java?

*Contract* means the classes which implement the *interface* you have declared will have agreed with the *contract* (methods) of the interface which simply means it will definitely going to add implementation of the abstract methods of interface.Let's check following example,

```
interface Teacher {
    void teach();
}
```

Note that every teacher of any Subject i.e `ScienceTeacher`, `EnglishTeacher` *(consider them as classes which are implementing Teacher)* etc. will going to do one common thing which is they will definitely *teach* yes differently but definitely.

On the other hand when you declare method in super class which is not abstract then it is sure enough that the child of that class will have default behavior as it's super class have. Yes it can change the behavior but will *bind* to have common *protocol* or functionality that it's parent can have.Consider following example,

```
class Parent {
   public void sleep() { 
      System.out.println("Sleeping At 10 PM.")
   }
}
```

Now, note here that every child of `Parent` will sleep at 10 PM and yes it can change the time for it's own but *protocol* says it will *sleep* for sure.

Answer (score 1):

They are very similar, but they emphasize different things.

When I read about a protocol, I'm thinking primarily about the flow of information. My mind is mostly focused on what happens when everything works well: if I give X, then I'll get Y.

When I read about a contract, I'm primarily thinking about the edge cases. My mind is focused less on the common cases, and more on the edge cases. In other words, I'm thinking about the terms of the contract: what am I promising, and what am I promised in return? For instance, maybe I promise that the argument to the method is not `null`; and maybe the method promises that, if I keep up my end of the bargain, it'll return a non-negative integer.

Of course, you can express either one of those ideas in terms of the other. If you really dig into the protocol, you may get into something like "if the argument is a `null`, the result is a `NullPointerException`." That's a more protocol-based way of looking at it, rather than the contract-based approach of, "hey, don't give me a `null`! If you do, I'll throw an exception at you!"

Yet another way of looking at it is that a protocol is about expanding the scope of your program (you're adding ways in which you can give or receive information), while a contract is about constricting the scope of the program (you're establishing bound on the inputs you receive, or on the outputs you return).